# Is this homework problem on T-joins wrong?

Tags: graph-theory, co.combinatorics, approximation-algorithms, optimization, linear-programming

[image]

In Question 9.3a, it states that if $T=V$, then the minimum cost perfect matching is the minimum cost T-join. Is this actually true? I think I have a counterexample which I have drawn [image]below.

Comment: The claim is true of the G  is a metric space. That is,  if you take the shortest path distances induced by the edge lengths and complete  the graph then T-join on V is same  as min-cost perfect matching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement of the problem is incorrect.

But $T$-joins are indeed very much related to the perfect matching problem. What the theorem that 9.3a is supposed to be conveying is:

Assume $G$ is connected.

Suppose that $T = V$. The minimum $T$-join can be found as follows: construct a complete graph $G'$ such that the weight on an edge (a,b) in $G'$ is the length of the shortest path between vertices $a$ and $b$ in $G$. Now, find a minimum weight perfect matching in $G'$. This gives the minimum $T$-join in $G$.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for.